# How to "create the video" after file uploaded to DailyMotion using c#

Tags: c#, dailymotion-api

Im following the instructions from [here](https://developer.dailymotion.com/guides/upload#upload-video-steps) to publish a new video on DailyMotion, using c# and a WebClient.
i successfully got the auth-token, then an upload url, then the actual file to upload. im stuck at step 4, called: "create the video"
it states to POST `url=<the url i got from previous step>` to https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos (with the Authorization token in the header), but all my attempts result in "bad request" - without further explanation.

any ideas?

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
var createRequest = $"url={videoUpload.url}";
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {authToken.access_token}");
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var createVideo = client.UploadString("https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos", "POST", createRequest);
}

also tried:
var createRequest = $"url={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(videoUpload.url)}";
```

Comment: you dont seem to be sending a file..

Comment: correct. publishing a new video on DailyMotion is a 5 step process: 1-get an auth token, 2-request an upload link, 3-upload the file (using 2nd step response), 4-create a video from the uploaded file, and finally 5-publish the new video. i'm stuck at step 4 (my video was already uploaded, and got a unique url im supposed to use at step 4)

Comment: you'd need to post more of your code.  As the process looks pretty simple on their website, but you're only posting us one small chunk, we cant see if you're checking part 3 uploading worked, and that you sent the file and checked that that worked.. etc

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and my video was created successfully. As explained in our [documentation](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#status-codes) a 400 error is related to a missing/invalid parameter.

I assume you are trying to send the upload url (returned in step 2) instead of the url returned by step 3 (url of your uploaded file).

You can find an article (with examples of returned values) which use a simplified way to upload on Dailymotion [here.](https://developer.dailymotion.news/tutorial/upload-new-video-api/)